# How can I limit my martingale and ani_martingle code to a specific number?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I have this martingale and ani_martingle code and I need it will be limited to a specific number and don't go further than this.
for example, if I chose 4, the martingale limit to 4 times (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 1,2) and repeated again from 1
could you help me, please?
thanks

```
f_martingale_wins_multiplier(_multiplier) =>
    _return = float(na)
    change_1 = change(strategy.losstrades)
    change_2 = change(strategy.wintrades)
    change_3 = change(strategy.eventrades)
    _return := na(_return[1]) ? 1 : change_1 > 0 ? 1 : 
       change_2 > 0 or change_3 > 0 ? _return[1] * _multiplier : _return[1]
    _return 
f_martingale_loss_multiplier(_multiplier) =>
    _return = float(na)
    change_1 = change(strategy.wintrades)
    change_2 = change(strategy.losstrades)
    change_3 = change(strategy.eventrades)
    _return := na(_return[1]) ? 1 : change_1 > 0 ? 1 : 
       change_2 > 0 or change_3 > 0 ? _return[1] * _multiplier : _return[1]
    _return

mode = int(na)
change_1 = change(strategy.losstrades)
mode := change(strategy.wintrades) > 0 ? 1 : change_1 > 0 ? -1 : nz(mode[1], 1)

f_martingale_wins_multiplier__1 = f_martingale_wins_multiplier(wins_multiplier)
f_martingale_loss_multiplier__1 = f_martingale_loss_multiplier(losses_multiplier)
trade_multiplier = mode > 0 ? f_martingale_wins_multiplier__1 : f_martingale_loss_multiplier__1

trade_size = input(defval=0.01, title='Base trade value:')
trade_leverage = input(defval=1, title='Base Leverage value:')
trade_size_multiplied = trade_size * trade_leverage * trade_multiplier

limited time martingale
```